# Continuity definitions on non-compact subsets

Tags: general-topology

At the top of the wikipedia articles on [Hölder condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition), [Lipschitz Continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) and others, the chain of logic is as follows:
On a compact subspace of a metric space: 
$$Continuously Differentiable \subseteq Lipschitz Continuous \subseteq \alpha-Hölder Continuous \subseteq Uniformly Continuous \subseteqq Continuous$$

There's a nice proof $Uniformly Continuous \subseteqq Continuous$ on compact metric spaces [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous).

$f(x) = x^2$ is a function which is continuous, but [not uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503093/proving-fx-x2-is-not-uniformly-continuous-on-the-real-line). It is however continuously differentiable, but [not Lipschitz continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242793/lipschitz-continuity-of-fx-to-x2).

My question is, do any of the inclusions above hold when we relax the imposition of compactness? (is, for example, the branch Lipschitz $\subseteq$ Hölder always true?)

Comment: Well, LipschitzContinuous $⊆$ $α$-HölderContinuous $⊆$ UniformlyContinuous $⊆$ Continuous holds in general. Compactness gives you ContinuouslyDifferentiable $⊆$ LipschitzContinuous and Continuous $⊆$ UniformlyContinuous (note the order).

Comment: (I mean $α$-Hölder for $a ∈ (0, 1)$, for $α=1$ we got Lipschitz and for $α=0$, we got bounded. Note that continuous $⊆$ bounded on compact.)